# Problems in developing a super simple js framework as an exercise with objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm sure my question will be relatively simple to answer, but as a beginner I'm really struggling.

So I've learned (at least I think i have) from a variety of sources the basics of Javascript, however I'm really struggling with objects, classes and syntax. I completely understand the concept, I've been playing around with various programming languages at basic levels for years, however, I'm struggling in implementing what I've learned in JS.

Basically I'm attempting to develop, as an exercise to prove my learnings a simple framework to make visual novel games. So my entire framework can be simplified to two basic objects, a scene and a character. So I'm attempting to flesh out my character object like so:

```
function character (race,gender,age)
{
    this.race = race;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}

//lets make an elf race based on the character prototype
var elfRace = new character("elf","m",100);
```

Basically my objective is to accomplish the following hierarchy

> Character
>
> Race 1 Race 2 Race 3
>
> ActualChar ActualChar ActualChar ActualChar ActualChar

so my final character will derive from the defined Race, which will derive from the character object.

Now my question is, I cant figure out how to set the Race to be derived from the Character. Do I declare character as the proto for Race? or do I

```
var newrace = new Character();
```

and how do I add additional "skills" or "parameters" to the races? so an elf race should have text: +5 and a demon race strength: +5, but these parameters should only be added at the race object level.

I've tried to keep it as to the point and brief as I can, but if you want more details about what I'm attempting to do, I've written a blog post about it too, if more details are required at:  http://www.endangeredpixel.com/

hope I can get some help on the issue, I've tried researching more on objects, hierarchy and prototypes, but I either get overly simplistic explanations and tutorials, or rants, rambles and extremely advanced tutorials beyond my skill level. I'm struggling to find explanations here at the intermediate stage :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this.. Although you can make less or even more constructors depending how you prefer. Now I'm using Character, Race, and Player (actual character). You could use different Race constructors like ElfRace, DemonRace but for something simple like 2 races you could just use one like I did. This is the general idea and you can modify it to fit your specific needs.

```
function Character(gender, age) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}

function Race(gender, age, race) {
    Character.call(this, gender, age); //inherit from Character
    this.race = race;
    if (race == 'elf') {
        this.dexterity = 5;
    } else if (race == 'demon') {
        this.strength = 5;   
    }; // you could check for more races here.
}

function Player(name, age, gender, race) {
    Race.call(this, gender, age, race); //inherit from Race
    this.name = name;
}

var player1 = new Player("Legolas", 100, "m", "elf");
alert(player1.name); //Legolas
alert(player1.age); //100 years old
alert(player1.gender); //m
alert(player1.race); //elf
alert(player1.dexterity); //5
alert(player1.strength); // undefined because elf's have dexterity not strength
```

In this example I created a player1 with the name of Legolas, age of 100, male and a race of elf. Here is also a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj4YT/)**

If you want to add more races then you have to update the if statement in the Race constructor to assign the skills for the specific race you want to add.

Comment: Interesting! i did not know about the .call function. I'll give this a go, however i'm curious as to whether there is an alternate solution to have the child object fully inherit all the properties of the parent without having to explicitly declare it in a .call as you have done above.
The reason for this, is that I have plans to write a variety of visual novels, and whilst i've simplified my context above, im hoping to create a compendium of races and sub races and other derivatives i'm planning to create, which I can then use to create the main character and npc's in the visual novel.

Comment: , so I may need to go back and make changes to the base character class, which I would then want to propagate to the child classes.

by using the .call method above, I would have to update each of the child classes that I would want affected right?

Comment: If you want to keep things really generic then you have to decide which characteristics you want every charater and npc will have like name, age, gender etc. and then use those in the constructors. After that you can add build more constructors for each game that will use the generic ones to build upon and then add the specific characteristic you  need extra on the specific constructor of that game.
As I said this is just a general idea. How you want to implement it to fit your needs its totally up to you. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Here is another example. http://jsfiddle.net/mj4YT/1/ You can use the character constructor in every game and in each specific game you can change the Race constructors. Here I created 2, ElfRace, DemonRace. So keep the gereral characteristics that every character should have in the character constructor and in each game alter the Race constructors for example.